# Inject $rootscope into services module

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

How would I inject `$rootscope` into wenzey.services so it is accessible across my application?

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    /**
     *
     */
    angular
        .module('wenzey.services', '$rootScope', [])

        $rootScope.type = "consumer";

})();
```

This is the error message I am currently getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module wenzey due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module wenzey.services due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'modulesToLoad' is not an array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong definition for a module. You are mixing a module with a service. You need to understand the below to use them properly:

1. You specify a module as a dependency of other module in module definition. E.g.

   ```
   angular
     .module('wenzy.services', [])
     .factory('AppService', function () {
       // Add methods
     });
   ```

   Now you can use the module `wenzy.services` as a dependency while defining module **wenzy.controllers** as below:

   ```
   angular
     .module('wenzy.controllers', ['wenzy.services']);
   ```
2. You inject a service in another service/ controller while defining the service/ controller . E.g. We have injected the service `AppService` in the **AppController** below

   ```
   angular
     .module('wenzy.controllers', ['wenzy.services'])
     .controller('AppController', function (AppService) {
       // Add controller defintion
     })
   ```

The `$rootScope` is a service provided by angular and can be injected into any service/ controller. You don't need to add that as part of module definition.